# How Do I Make A Controller Accessible Menu | Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a menu on a game I'm working on. The menu consists of a few logos in the form of images, and 2 buttons in a canvas. I'm trying to give the game full controller support. How do I make it so that the controller can navigate through the menus?

The controller I'm using is a wired Xbox 360 Controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "First selected" in the event Manager. Thats all.